# How to filter records from database with condition

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Hibernate DAO method which returns all users.

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from com.model.User");
    List<User> users = query.list();
    session.flush();
    return users;
}
```

The `User` entity has a `profession` property. I would like to query only the users whose profession equals to `Developer`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes. Filter the list before passing it to your JSP. Or use <c:if test="${user.profession = 'Developer'}">. How comes you know about c:forEach, but not about c:if?

Comment: Seriously, please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Thank you for the fast respond, Actually I want to do it with the first way(Filter the list before passing it to your JSP) Iam gonna add how I write it in DAO. Also I don't know how do it so if there is an example it will be better.

Comment: Well, then add a method findUsersByProfession() in your DAO, and call that method. Implement it by using a JPQL query, as explained in all JPA tutorials. That has absolutely nothing to do with JSP and the JSTL.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I did what you say and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using JAVA8 Streams to solve your problem?

Let's say that you are retrieving a List of Users, like this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("from com.model.User");
List<User> users = query.list();
```

Now, just do this to filter by profession:

```
users = users.stream().
     filter(user -> user.getProfession.equals("Developer")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Likely because if you have a case where you have thousands of `User` records and you're interested in a small percentage of rows that have the desired predicate, you're going to achieve faster performance by passing the predicate to the database as a `WHERE` condition rather than streaming the entire database table to the JVM's memory and then applying the predicate.